# File drag and drop event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

I'm trying to find a way of letting users drag and drop individual files into an area on my page that can then get submitted along with all my other form data.

In my research I've found multiple "drag and drop" upload scripts but they all do way, way too much. I want to handle the actual uploading myself and just provide a way for users to upload files without hitting the *browse* button.

Is there an event in jquery (or something similar) that I should be looking for?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: A complete library for that is jQuery File Upload (http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). OSS and MIT licensed.

Answer (score 19):

I came across this question while researching some AJAX file upload techniques.

I created a drag and drop upload script today (its still in proof of concept stage but heres the basic steps that I took.

```
$('drag-target-selector').on('drop', function(event) {

 //stop the browser from opening the file
 event.preventDefault();

 //Now we need to get the files that were dropped
 //The normal method would be to use event.dataTransfer.files
 //but as jquery creates its own event object you ave to access 
 //the browser even through originalEvent.  which looks like this
 var files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

 //Use FormData to send the files
 var formData = new FormData();

 //append the files to the formData object
 //if you are using multiple attribute you would loop through 
 //but for this example i will skip that
 formData.append('files', files[0]);

 }
```

now you can send formData to be processed by a php script or whatever else you want to use. I didn't use jquery in my script as there a lot of issues with it it seemed easier to use regular xhr. Here is that code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);

    };


    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
                    //updates a <progress> tag to show upload progress
                    $('progress').val(complete);

            }
    };

xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: I found that only listening to "drop" wouldn't catch the file in Chrome, it only stopped when i listened to both "dragover" and "drop" on the given element and did .stopPropagation() & .preventDefault() on both events